# How to Know the Which IP-Port belongs to Which Instance of the Virtual Machine Scale Set

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-vm

I have an Azure Windows VMSS with 2 instances in running state with a load balancer:

- LB Rule - Port 80
- Inbound NAT Rule - Frontend Port 50000, Service Port 3389

My VMSS Public IP is `20.1.13.195`

I'm connecting with 1st VM instance using RDP Service - **20.1.13.195:50000**
2nd VM Instance with - **20.1.13.195:50001**.

- **VMSS Name is: TestWinVMSS01**
- **Instance1 Name: TestWinVMSS01_0**
- **Instance2 Name: TestWinVMSS01_1**

I'm able to connect with 1st VMSS Instances using (its Public IP : Front end Port) in RDP Connection Service.

I also tested with the IP `20.1.13.195:50002` which is connection **failed** because there is no 3rd instance. This is as expected.

**My Doubt is When I'm Connecting with the Instance IP (20.1.13.195:50001), Can I Confirm it is connecting to 2nd VM Instance. If yes, how?**

Comment: Once you RDP to the machine you can just look at the machine name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @[SamCogan](https://serverfault.com/users/48/sam-cogan).

After you sign in to the VM using port 50001, check computername to
see if it is 2nd VM Instance. Several methods:

- Right-click on Start -- Run, cmd.exe At prompt type: set comp and
  press enter. You should see COMPUTERNAME=TestWinVMSS01_1
- Right-click on Start -- System You should see Device name
  TestWinVMSS01_1
- Right-click on Start -- Run, sysdm.cpl This will show you full
  computer name